# The Error in this code is - validate CRUD permission before SOQL/DML operation (rule: secuirity - apexCRUDVioloation) what is the probable solution?

Tags: apex, soql, crud

```java
public with sharing class VehicleController {
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static List<Vehicle__c> getVehicleList() {
        return [SELECT Id, Veichle_Name__c, Rental_Rate__c, Make__c, Registration_Number__c, Vehicle_Image__c, Emission__c 
                FROM Vehicle__c];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This rule violation states that appropriate permissions are not checked before DML / SOQL.

After `Spring'20` release , we can easily apply CRUD & Object permissions using the WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED in SOQL as below :

```
    public with sharing class VehicleController {
      @AuraEnabled(Cacheable = true) 
      public static List < Vehicle__c > getVehicleList() {
          List<Vehicle_c> vehiclesList;
           try {
               vehiclesList = [SELECT Id, Veichle_Name__c, Rental_Rate__c, Make__c, Registration_Number__c, Vehicle_Image__c, Emission__c FROM Vehicle__c WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED];
           } catch(System.QueryException ex) {
                System.debug(ex.getMessage());
            }
        return vehiclesList;
      }
    
    }
```

- [WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_with_security_enforced.htm#apex_classes_with_security_enforced)
- [ApexCRUDViolation](https://docs.pmd-code.org/latest/pmd_rules_apex_security.html#apexcrudviolation)